# console.log - written in location bar and not in console panel

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a standard form taking values from one textbox `<input type="text" ...` manipulating it and putting the information either into a div or another textbox as the case may be.

Everything was at is was until I made a mistake. I added a `<form>` around my textboxes and didn't add a `return false` when calling the function. It took a few secs to figure out the problem but I noticed something interesting: the console.log information was placed in the location bar.

```
function getTotal(){
....
var total=end-start;
....
console.log(total);
}
```

As expected (because the return false wasn't included) the divs were not written to and the textboxes were not written to but .... look at the screenshot.

How does this happen? Why is it written to the location bar?

SCREENSHOT BELOW: (I can't create a jsfiddle for it as it requires a form submit button.)
I entered 22 in `<input type="text" id="start">` textbox and 77 in  `<input type="text" id="end">`

[image]

Everything works with:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="start" id="start"><br/>
<input type="text" name="end" id="end"><br/>
<button onClick="checkTotal(); return false; ">Check Total</button><br/>
<input type="text" id="aaa"><br/>
</form>
```

Remove the return false and it writes to the location bar:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="start" id="start"><br/>
<input type="text" name="end" id="end"><br/>
<button onClick="checkTotal();">Check Total</button><br/>
<input type="text" id="aaa"><br/>
</form>
```

The javascript is this (all this has been pared down for easier reading)

```
    function checkTotal(){

    var start=document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end=document.getElementById('end').value;
    var total=end-start;
    var writeTotal=document.getElementById('total');
    writeTotal.innerHTML=total;
    var abc=document.getElementById('aaa').value=total;
    console.log(total);

    }
```

Comment: You mean, the default behavior of `<form>`s, which you are no longer preventing by `return false;`?

Comment: Amazing ... someone who knows Ajax, but doesn't know the original behavior of pages that use GET method in forms to submit form content. In that case, the parameters will ALWAYS be appended to the URL as a so-called query string

Comment: You're logging `55`, but it's putting `22` and `77` in the location bar. What makes you think `console.log` is doing i?

Comment: Yeah. I commented on that below. I guess it's time to take a break. I looked at this and thought it was all the console.log and not the standard form submission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a form with an implict `GET` method type. It's intended to add the form values to the URL, as URL-encoded parameters, according to the field names.

So, the result you're seeing is completely unrelated to `console.log`.

Comment: First. I got to this by error. (I had forgotten to put in return false when calling the function.) Second. It appears whether method="post" or get is there. I know how to make it NOT happen. I just want to know WHY it happens.

Comment: Do you know, then, what `return false` is supposed to do?

Comment: I forgot about the `return false` part. Edited to remove useless suggestion. @devnull69

Comment: Yes. Prevent the form from submitting the data. Oh. FKKK. It has nothing to do with the console.log.  Must h-a-v-e more coffee.

Comment: My last question was for @Mayo :-)

Comment: @Mayo In any case, it should not happen with POST method.